# redirection to multiple ttys in c

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system

I see that I can do freopen to redirect stdout going to a console to one another tty. I am trying to redirect the same to multiple terminals including the console. Console is where the program is running. What is the best way to do it?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what platform you're using, but assuming you can find the file path to the TTY you'd like to redirect to, you can call `freopen` on the `stdout` file descriptor. However, that would close the initial file descriptor, which doesn't sound like your desired behavior. A file descriptor can only point to one file.

The easiest C solution is probably going to be a wrapper around printf that calls it on all of your specified files. You might be able to do something with threading, but that's likely to complicate things.

If you're on a *nix system, I suggest using tee which is made for outputting to stdout and secondary files.

Comment: This sounds good. Actually, I was toying with the idea to dup the stdout fd. Then freopen, in a loop to each of the tys in the array and call printf. This is for linux.

Comment: Well then, no need to reinvent the wheel - pipe it to `tee`. If you want it to be scriptable ( `./foo` instead of `./foo | tee /dev/ttyA /Dev/ttyB...`, you can call fork, dup2, and exec to call tee.

Comment: well, the problem is this should happen in c program. The ttys are set and unset by users from clients.

Comment: Then it sounds like your best bet is to make a wrapper for printf. In your code, you'll need a way of initializing each file handle, a function to print to each file handle, and if you want to be nice, functions to close the file descriptors. I'm not sure what you mean as far as clients setting the TTYs, so however that works will dictate how your functions work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really easy way to do this like with `freopen`. You need some wrapper that takes the input and writes it to each output tty individually.

For example there is the `tee` program that multiplexes its input to stdout and a number of files. You could for example create a pipe in C that is connected to `tee /dev/ttyX /dev/ttyY ...`. Then you can replace stdout with the pipe file descriptor and you will get the desired behaviour.